# Meteor field selection based on criteria

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection that contains posts.

The post document contains a blurred and none-blurred image (**blurredImage** and **image** key in the document).

If the current user is the owner of the post or the current user has purchased the content the image key can be pushed to the client.

When this is not the case the image key cannot be pushed (because of security). Otherwise anyone could just query the local mongo and see the full image url, while they didn't pay for it.

Now my question is. What is the best way of doing this kind of field selection in a publish method?

I don't see a way to do a conditional field selection.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your publication:

```
const user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
if (user.hasPermissionToViewImage) return Documents.find({}, { fields: image: 1, *everything else you need* });
return Documents.find({}, { fields: image: 0, *everything else you need* });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit tricky because the conditional needs to be evaluated on each image based on another field (the `ownerId`). However you can return an *array of cursors* in your publication, each with its own query criteria and field filters. In your case:

```
Meteor.publish('myPublication',()=>{
  const ownedByMe = Posts.find({ ownerId: this.userId },{ fields: { image: 1, foo: 1, bar: 1 }});
  const notOwnedByMe = Posts.find({ ownerId: { $ne: this.userId }},{ fields: blurredImage: 1, foo: 1, bar: 1 }});
  return [ownedByMe,notOwnedByMe];
});
```

where `foo` and `bar` are keys that you want to return in either case.

@sdybskiy Note that you can't mix field inclusion and exclusion in one query. Inclusion implies that all other fields are excluded and vice-versa.